# How to seperate Javafx(non fxml) to a fxml and a controller? (Invocation target exception)

Tags: java, opencv, javafx, javafx-8

I am building a application which can show  live feed from my webcam. So I have been searching for sample codes as there was no webcam support in JavaFX and finally I found the code (javaFX+ OpenCV).
But I am using fxml for my application and the sample code I found is a Non-Fxml.

The following code is the sample code which I am not able to *break it into FXML and its controller*
**From here I find 2 ways 
1:To break the non-fxml code
2:To use the non-fxml sample code in my application. So is it possible to  use the non-FXML java  code with the FXML application?**
or is there any other way?

For those who require webcam support in javaFX this snippet works perfectly fine. The only requirement is OPENCV libraries.
Though I cannot take credit for the code.
Thank You in advance

```
package test;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer; 
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

public class Camera2 extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
private static final int SCENE_W = 640;
private static final int SCENE_H = 480;


VideoCapture videoCapture;

Canvas canvas;
GraphicsContext g2d;
Stage stage;
AnimationTimer timer;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    this.stage = stage;

    initOpenCv();

    canvas = new Canvas(SCENE_W, SCENE_H);
    g2d = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    g2d.setStroke(Color.GREEN);

    Group group = new Group(canvas);

    Scene scene = new Scene(group, SCENE_W, SCENE_H);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();

    timer = new AnimationTimer() {

        Mat mat = new Mat();

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {

            videoCapture.read(mat);

            Image image = mat2Image(mat);

            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        }
    };
    timer.start();

}

private void initOpenCv() {

    //setLibraryPath();
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    videoCapture = new VideoCapture();
    videoCapture.open(0);

    System.out.println("Camera open: " + videoCapture.isOpened());

    stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        public void handle(WindowEvent we) {

            timer.stop();
            videoCapture.release();

            System.out.println("Camera released");

        }
    });

}

public static Image mat2Image(Mat mat) {
    MatOfByte buffer = new MatOfByte();
    Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", mat, buffer);
    return new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toArray()));
}

}
```

I tried using the above code in mycontroller file

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Canvas canvas;

@FXML
private Button button_start;
private static final int SCENE_W = 640;
private static final int SCENE_H = 480;

VideoCapture videoCapture;
GraphicsContext g2d;
Stage stage;
AnimationTimer timer;


@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    //   this.stage = stage;
    initOpenCv();

    canvas = new Canvas(SCENE_W, SCENE_H);
    g2d = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    g2d.setStroke(Color.GREEN);

    Group group = new Group(canvas);

    Scene scene = new Scene(group, SCENE_W, SCENE_H);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();

    timer = new AnimationTimer() {

        Mat mat = new Mat();

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {

            videoCapture.read(mat);

            Image image = mat2Image(mat);

            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        }
    };
    timer.start();

}

private void initOpenCv() {

    //setLibraryPath();
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    videoCapture = new VideoCapture();
    videoCapture.open(0);

    System.out.println("Camera open: " + videoCapture.isOpened());

    stage.setOnCloseRequest((WindowEvent we) -> {
        timer.stop();
        videoCapture.release();

        System.out.println("Camera released");
    });

}
```

But I got the following error

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/home/anurag/NetBeansProjects/Test2/dist/run1986258874/Test2.jar!/test2/FXMLDocument.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at test2.Test2.start(Test2.java:22)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at test2.FXMLDocumentController.initOpenCv(FXMLDocumentController.java:104)
at test2.FXMLDocumentController.initialize(FXMLDocumentController.java:61)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
... 17 more
Exception running application test2.Test2
```

Comment: You can add non-fxml code in the controller inside `initialize()` method.

Comment: Still I want to try the same code by having a controller and FXML file. Can it be done? If I add it in Initialize() it still uses scene and stage... Though it solves the problem.. but I still want to know for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of what you exactly want, but I guess you can adapt the code you exposed as it is just a Group with a Canvas.
For instance :

### groupwithcanvas.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>

<Group xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="GroupWithCanvasController">
    <Canvas fx:id="myCanvas"></Canvas>
</Group>
```

### GroupWithCanvasController.java

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class GroupWithCanvasController implements Initializable {


    @FXML
    private Canvas myCanvas;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        // DO STUFFS

    }
}
```

### MainApp.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainApp extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getClassLoader().getResource("groupwithcanvas.fxml"));
        Group group = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You will have to adapt all the OpenCV logic in `initialize()` but It should be feasible.

Comment: I apologize if I was not clear but yeah the above example helps. Thank You!! #Kwoinkwoin

Comment: You are welcome! :)
If you have no other comments, you can mark your question as solved by accepting this answer. :)