# Location error when trying to separate logic from view when using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, logic

As the title suggest, I just want to separate (**organize**) the files inside my project, before everything I've read this:

1. [How to seperate Javafx(non fxml) to a fxml and a controller? (Invocation target exception)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408507/how-to-seperate-javafxnon-fxml-to-a-fxml-and-a-controller-invocation-target)
2. [Is there a way to modularize a JavaFX application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665253/is-there-a-way-to-modularize-a-javafx-application)
3. [How to seperate logic from controller JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913531/how-to-seperate-logic-from-controller-javafx)

This is the most approached answer.

4. [How to separate my gui in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470551/how-to-separate-my-gui-in-javafx)

But it's no quite clear for me still tho, (perhaps it's about I don't understand grammar cuz english is not my native lang).

I tried to replicate the last one manually, but still can't figure how should I point to the fxml files.

Here is my structure:

[My project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u67Y3.png)

The code for my main app:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
/**
 * Principal
 * @author Adrian
 *
 */
public class Login extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,300,200);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            Image icono = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/SiLi/src/main/recursos/img/usuario.gif"));
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(icono);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }   
}
```

The error I get:

```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at org.ajfmo.sili.core.Login.start(Login.java:19)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You can find more and more Q/A  like what you want.For your error you should verify your path of fxml file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying MVC With JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630415/nullpointer-location-on-javafx-fxmlloader and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828952/jafafx-load-fxml-file-error-null-pointer-exception

Comment: Surely it should be `getClass().getResource("/fxml/login.fxml")`? Not sure what the exception has to do with MVC, you just have the wrong path to the FXML file.

Comment: @James_D thank you,that solved part of the trouble, and another issue with class not found exception because I was not providing the proper controller path to the fxml, I had to address with whole package name, I'm trying to learn by myself since where I live there's no good formation on programing.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine Thank you, I gathering the provided information and studying it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue folowing [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d) comment, still not clear to me why this happen (I guess it have something to do with absolute and relative paths and the current working directory). Anyhow I managed to organize my project into correct folders.

Using the information provided by James:

> Surely it should be getClass().getResource("/fxml/login.fxml")? Not sure what the exception has to do with MVC, you just have the wrong path to the FXML file. – [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d)

And pointing at the correct path or location of my "Login.java" class controller in the Login.fxml file, try to point to the package container of the controller like this:

```
fx:controller="org.ajfmo.sili.controlador.CLogin"
```

Allowed my to solve the issue and keep in the track...

Thanks for helping me out.